# Pushing my Python Discord Bot onto Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli, buildpack

I wrote a program in VS Code for a Discord bot, and I am trying to run it in Heroku. I was using the Heroku CLI and navigated to the folder with the code in my Command Prompt (I'm on Windows). I tried to add and push my main code, but I got the error in the picture below.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue? I am using Windows and my code is in VS Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that heroku is unable to determine the language of your project.

You should add a `requirements.txt` file with the python package names used in your project to allow heroku to detect it as a python project.
Other options include using a `setup.py` file or `Pipfile`.

You can also manually set the buildpack using

```bash
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

in the heroku CLI

For more information check the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support)